# SDL Xcode. No errors, but surface won't appear

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cocoa, sdl

I'm trying to set up SDL with Xcode using the tutorial here.
http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-tutorial-basics

I have everything set up correctly according to this tutorial, and there are no errors after building. The only problem is that when I run the program, the SDL_Surface never appears. The console says nothing and no errors are thrown. I've been searching for solutions for says, but I am unable to find anything that relates to my issue. I put my code up here on Git if anyone would like to check it out and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks so much!

https://github.com/syobonaction/rubicon.git

Comment: I'm not an Xcode user, but can you trace in a debugger? Are `Surf_Temp` and `Surf_Return` loaded properly in `OnLoad`? Is `OnRender` called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a silly but easy mistake to make!

In your project, you have included main.m (included in a default cocoa application project) and have not included SDLMain.m, so your SDL code is never executing, and instead you are just running a blank Cocoa application!

To fix this, click on SDLMain.m, open the utilities pane on the right, and click the checkbox to add SDLMain.m to your target. Next, go to Supporting Files in your left navigation pane, find main.m, and delete it from your project. You don't need main.m at all, because all it does is start a Cocoa application, which you don't want to do! (SDLMain.m will also start a cocoa application, but not before linking the cocoa application to the SDL system.)

Comment: Additionally, your current version of SDLMain.h might not compile. If not, just change the line `#include "SDL.h"` to `#include "SDL/SDL.h"` or `#include <SDL/SDL.h>`, whichever you've been using in your project.